# How to verify a user is a real Facebook user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook Javascript SDK from client side with a standart Facebook login button. When a user click the button I get user id from Facebook. Later I'm using Facebook PHP SDK from server side. I want to check the user id is a real user id. I searched some resources but I dont know I'm on the correct way. I using access token. My link is on the above. When I send request I get an error. Client id is my app id, client secret is secret key. Also when I send a request with curl I get an error. Which method I have to use?

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="public_profile,email,id" onlogin="checkLoginState()"></div>
```

**My link**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/oauth/access_token?client_id=1798****&client_secret=efba0a******&grant_type=client_credentials
```

**Error Code**

> {
>   "error": {
>   "message": "The request is invalid because the app is configured as a desktop app",
>   "type": "OAuthException",
>   "code": 1,
>   "fbtrace_id": "EG0HGBcdrvg"
>   }
>   }

**The another request result is**

> Facebook\Http\GraphRawResponse Object
>   (
>       [headers:protected] => Array
>           (
>               [WWW-Authenticate] => OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#100) You must provide an app access token or a user access token that is an owner or developer of the app"
>               [Access-Control-Allow-Origin] => *
>               [Pragma] => no-cache
>               [Cache-Control] => no-store
>               [x-fb-rev] => 2873744
>               [Content-Type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
>               [x-fb-trace-id] => HvnaZakHHGX
>               [facebook-api-version] => v2.2
>               [Expires] => Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
>               [Vary] => Accept-Encoding
>               [X-FB-Debug] => u2RDExwRJf06OIGbpCplHs5ZE2tQdUlWZDEFxJF0vWMcbt681uDHu/FLpewEfddPnyyBr4L/QwtxL2t+Sip9uw==
>               [Date] => Tue, 07 Mar 2017 12:52:51 GMT
>               [Transfer-Encoding] => chunked
>               [Connection] => keep-alive
>           )
>   [body:protected] => {"error":{"message":"(#100) You must provide an app access token or a user access token that is an owner or developer of the app","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"HvnaZakHHGX"}}
>       [httpResponseCode:protected] => 400
>   )

Comment: Before you can verify anything about your users, you need to [correct your Facebook Developers settings](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2367).

Comment: The JS SDK and the PHP SDK can interact via the cookies set under your domain. Check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_access_token_from_javascript for a simple example how to get the access token that was created via client-side login in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

To fix the error

`The request is invalid because the app is configured as a desktop app` you must re-configure your app and turn off the "Native or Desktop app" setting (see below)

[image]